# Issues accessing to a Docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask

I have a Flask server running on the 8090 port

```
...code of the Flask server...
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8090, debug=True)
```

Then I have the Dockerfile as follow:

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR home

MAINTAINER Califfo

# copy files into the image
ADD files /home/files
ADD ServerCategory.py /home
ADD requirements.txt /home

# install python3, pip and Flask
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip net-tools lsof && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# launch flask server
RUN python3 ServerCategory.py flask run
```

When I build the image and run the container with this command

```
docker build -t server_category . && docker run -p 8090:8090 -it --rm server_category
```

everything is OK.

- Running on http://0.0.0.0:8090/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 280-257-458

But I cannot connect to the server from my browser, for example with localhost:8090/.
I get this error

```
Error: Couldn't connect to server
```

Comment: Does it work from within the container? Try `docker exec <container-name> wget http://localhost:8090`.

Comment: You have no `entrypoint` or `cmd` declared in your Dockerfile. When you start your container it is closed immediately. Change your last `RUN` command to `CMD python3 ServerCategory.py flask run ` and re-try.

Comment: @nauer you should consider to make this comment a more detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As nauer says in the comments, one of the problems is that you don't have any ENTRYPOINT or CMD command on Dockerfile. So whenever you starts the container he will close immediately. With your docker run command, the container are still alive because you open the bash with the -it flags, but this is not the optimal approach.

For the problem "Error: Couldn't connect to server" you will need to give some more information, since the problem appears to be with flask and not with docker itself.